# regular expression to match all java imports except one with a certain ending

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, rad

I am trying to do a search and replace in eclipse on the imports in my java file but I cant get the search to match the imports I want.

In short I want to match all import statements except ones that end with a particular string.

so far I have **^import\s.*[^{STRINGTEXT}];$**

but this does not return the results I need. I have tried using related expressions from other questions on this site but none seem to work...I would guess that this is a special case. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't the character class just match any character that is not in `deorstCMST{}`? Also, how sure are you that there are no imports anywhere in your codebase with trailing whitespace at the end of the line?

Comment: Can you please post a real example of what you don't want to match ?

Comment: Are you using Java REs? If so, the use of "[" and "{" is wrong.

Comment: you probably don't want a character class, but probably something with negative look ahead with some `(?!(STRINGTEXT))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a small [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can do it easily

```
^import.*?(?<!BADSTRING);$
```

It match import then all chars up to `;`, checking that `;` not preceded by `BADSTRING`

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

[import .*(?!StoreModelTestCase){1};$](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O_QJjF4DRyNc1Tcs)

But I think it is not a really good idea, because, you can also use full qualified classnames within the source later.